# "Both of you know" or "Both of you knows"?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is correct?

> Both of you **know** about it.

or

> Both of you **knows** about it.

Comment: What is the rationale for _knows_? That's third person singular, but _both_ is plural and _you_ is second person. _Both know_ and _you know_ are the separate forms, so where does the -s come from?

Comment: But you can say, "*Each* of you knows..."

Comment: Shame this got migrated before anyone got a chance to ask the author where they had heard this usage.

Answer (score 6):

The "s" at the end of that verb is called a *third person singular "s"*, and as you can guess from the title, it's added to third person singular verbs only, which would be "he", "she", and "it", or any other noun that can be exchanged with either of those subject pronouns.

The subject in your sentence doesn't fit that category, 1. because it's not singular, 2. because it's not third person, so you don't need the "s".

> Both of you know about it.

Answer (score 2):

*Both* is the subject of your sentence, and it is what the verb should agree with. Since *Both* is plural, you should use the plural form *know*, not the third person singular *knows*.

> **Both** of you **know** about it.

*of you* modifies *Both*, and does not affect the verb's number.